# How do I maintain state for Dom.Document type variables between Start and execute method of a batch

Tags: apex, batch, dom, stateful

I want to create a XML Head in start method of a batch class. I was getting "System.SerializationException: Not Serializable: dom.Document" error for DOM. To handle this I declared all the variables as transient. But now my state is not being maintained between Start and execute method. Below is the code snippet.

```
global class XMLCreation implements Database.batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
global String xForm;
transient global Dom.Document document;
transient global Dom.Xmlnode xmlRoot;
transient global Dom.Xmlnode xmlHead;
transient global Dom.Xmlnode xmlModel;
transient global Dom.Xmlnode xmlInstance;
transient global Dom.Xmlnode xmlData;

public NonCascadingXformBatch(XYZ__c XYZ) {
    this.XYZ = XYZ;
}

/**
 * Start method
 */
global List<Question__c> start(Database.batchableContext batchableContext) {

    this.document = new Dom.Document();
    this.xmlRoot = this.document.createRootElement('h:html', null, null);

    this.xmlRoot.setNamespace('jr',<namespace>);
    this.xmlRoot.setNamespace('h', <xtz>);

    // Some query on question object

    this.xmlHead = this.xmlRoot.addChildElement('h:head',null,null);
    this.xmlHead.addChildElement('h:title',null,null).addTextNode(this.surveyVersion.Survey__r.Name);
    this.xmlModel = this.xmlHead.addChildElement('model',null,null);
    this.xmlInstance = this.xmlModel.addChildElement('instance',null,null);
    this.xmlData = this.xmlInstance.addChildElement('data',null,null);
    this.xmlData.setAttribute('id',surveyVersion.Id);
    return questions;
}

/**
 * Execute method
 */
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Question__c> questions) {
    for (Question__c question : questions) {
        setHeaderModel(this.xmlData, question.Name);
    }
}
```

In Exceute method "xmlData" is blank.

Comment: I realize you used the transient keyword because of the serialization.  By using transient variables, you won't be able to maintain state which is the cause of the issue your having. Is there a way to rewrite your code so that it gets saved to another variable for the purpose of state rather than an instance variable once created? Either that or perhaps not all of your variables need to be transient?

Comment: I need to add transient keyword to all variables for DOM to avoid serialization error. All these variables if not declared as transient give "System.SerializationException: Not Serializable: dom.Document" error. But by transient I can't maintain the state.  And if I save to any other varaible also it will be of same type and will need to declare those also transient.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you cannot or will not specify your desired end result. I will consider it on topic if you outline the document you are trying to create. Please use sufficient detail to understand what you are trying to serialize based on the records being processed. Ideally you should show a sample of the desired markup, even if it uses pseudo-code to get the point across.

Comment: My issue is not with the approach. My issue was with using a DOM in start method and maintaining state. If this approach has a limitation I can go for the other one and need not mention the details here because that is not required. Thanks a lot for you time again.

Comment: did you consider managing state yourself ? you could store the data somewhere else in the database than to rely on the standard mechanism. Or .. that is at least what I would try.

Comment: Samuel, yes thought so. But its like my customers can create unlimited XMLs anytime and saving XML in pieces. Now I am trying to form the XML in execute method only. My Head and Body will be formed side by side in execute method and then passed as string to the next batch where my csv will be processed and rest of the XML will be formed. In the last batch I will concatenate the two and type caste.

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, `transient` does *not* make your error go away. You just stop tracking that state. It does not make any sense to use `transient` variables in a `Stateful` batch.

Is it really state that you need to track between `execute` calls, though? Based on the code you have shared, it does not seem so. Consider building/manipulating your xml in the `execute` method itself.

```
global class XMLCreation implements Database.batchable<SObject>
{
    global Database.queryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([/*query*/]);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<SObject> questions)
    {
        // Build your XML here
        // Scoping locally will avoid serialization
        Dom.Document document;
        Dom.Xmlnode xmlRoot;
        Dom.Xmlnode xmlHead;
        Dom.Xmlnode xmlModel;
        Dom.Xmlnode xmlInstance;
        Dom.Xmlnode xmlData;

    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I really want to build some part of the xml in start method and then continue in execute method. I know using transient with stateful doesn't make sense. This is where I am stuck. If I don't use transient I get "System.SerializationException: Not Serializable: dom.Document" error for DOM variables

Comment: Please clarify *why* building this structure (which is not serializable) in the `execute` method is not an option. Right now it sounds like the answer is simply *because you don't want to*. You have to acknowledge the reality of the constraints imposed by the system at a certain point.

Comment: This is part of my requirement. I want to create XML head part in start method and then body part in execute method.Its not about how I want or not, its about what my scenario requires at the moment.  In short my head part will be created for all the records in one go and body requires more processing so need to create that in execute method in batches.

Comment: Is the entire batch creating one xml document? One per record?

Comment: No. We will be doing chaining of batches. My Head part will be done in start method. Then execute part will create body for the records. Then next batch will be called which will form next part of the body for a csv file.

Comment: So the entire point is to create a csv? Why use xml at all? You keep saying which method you need to put your logic in but not clarifying requirements or backing up your assessment with any sort of reasoning. Can you please edit your post with a concise example of what your end result should look like as an xml document or csv?

Comment: It's not about creating csv. Its about some part of the xml body will be created from a csv file which will have different cascading levels and other with normal records. I think it will be difficult for you to understand the entire scenario. Anyways Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I understand it may be complicated, but if you won't explain, how can we help? I'm voting to close unless you can add sufficient detail to enable an informed suggestion. You're going to *have to* compile it all in one go if you want to use a `Dom.Document`. There is no way around it. You can serialize something in your `execute` method and then write the output in your `finish` method, but without knowing your desired result, it's impossible to recommend a serialization scheme.